# C# - Why can't I change my int variables in another class?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, global-variables

Okay, so I have the following variables:

```
    public static int cookieCount = 0;
    public static int cursorCount = 0;
    public static int granCount = 0;
    public static int farmCount = 0;
    public static int mineCount = 0;
    public static int shipCount = 0;
    public static int alcCount = 0;
    public static int portalCount = 0;
    public static int timeCount = 0;

    public static int clickGain = 1;
    public static int cursorGain = 1;
    public static int granGain = 5;
    public static int farmGain = 10;
    public static int mineGain = 50;
    public static int shipGain = 100;
    public static int alcGain = 500;
    public static int portalGain = 10000;
    public static int timeGain = 123456;

    public static int cursorPrice = 20;
    public static int granPrice = 100;
    public static int farmPrice = 500;
    public static int minePrice = 1000;
    public static int shipPrice = 10000;
    public static int alcPrice = 50000;
    public static int portalPrice = 500000;
    public static int timePrice = 1500000;

    public static float cursorSpeed = 1F;
    public static float granSpeed = 2F;
    public static float farmSpeed = 5F;
    public static float mineSpeed = 5F;
    public static float shipSpeed = 10F;
    public static float alcSpeed = 15F;
    public static float portalSpeed = 10F;
    public static float timeSpeed = 15F;
```

And I have that in Global.cs. So when I'm in Form1 I use this:

```
    private void cookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Global.cookieCount + Global.clickGain;
    }
```

I get an error.

`Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.`

So common sense tells me that static varibles are not changeable, but changing static to dynamic throws these errors:

`Invalid token 'int' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

`Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

`'CookieClicker.Global.cookieCount' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property`
So I'm stumped on how to do this.

All I want is when cookie_Click runs, Global.clickGain is to be added to cookieCount, but I want the variables to be global.

Comment: I think you are missing `=` after `+`. Try `Global.cookieCount += Global.clickGain;`

Comment: What is the meaning of `Global.cookieCount + Global.clickGain;` when you loss the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not assigning the result to anything.

Assign the result to `Global.cookieCount`, like this:

```
Global.cookieCount += Global.clickGain;
```

OR like this

```
Global.cookieCount = Global.cookieCount + Global.clickGain;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, a newbie error on my part! I'll try that now :)